# Azure File Storage - Access Policies Identifier

Tags: azure, file-storage, azure-files

I have a basic HTML page with an img, although the below is a random image, once implemented this will become logos etc.

With the research already undertaken I know I can create a SAS, which can be used to grant access to files, however I am not keen on the url containing the ‘sig’ for the following reasons:

- Over complicates the url as this also contains the start/end date
- I would expect that if the access keys are regenerated I would need to update the sig through the site whereas the si just references a name
- I don't think I would need to provide the start/end date if using a si

I am also make the file share public, but again I am not keen on this and other file shares cannot be public. I then looked into Access Policies.

The file share has two 'Access Policies'

•   Read
•   Read/Write

I have uploaded one image: Lake-chon-high-resolution-Large.jpg
Within the img src I have added the following: https://xxx.file.core.windows.net/filestorage/Lake-chon-high-resolution-Large.jpg?si=accesspolicyid

My knowledge is very limited and I am struggling to understand where I put the identifier in the URI or whether in fact I can do this.

I have been googling without much luck barring one person mentioning they used &si=MyIdentifier, which I have tried. They also had a start and end date, which confused me as surely you don’t need that information if you are referencing the identifier, as the identifier holds the start and end date.

This is the error I have received. “The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.”

Any help?

Comment: `however I am not keen on the url containing the ‘sig’` -> Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: A couple of reasons: 1) I think it over complicates the url 2) As this is customer facing I dont want customers to be able to locate our sig and therefore have access to other files within that folder 3) I would expect that if the access keys are regenerated I would need to update the sig through the site whereas the si just references a name. 4) I don't think I would need to provide the start/end date if using a si

Comment: Please update your question with these concerns of yours. I’ll try to address these and provide an answer to your original query.